Puppeteer: How to Disable "Change Your Password" (Password Leak Detection) Popup in Chrome?
I am using Puppeteer for browser automation, and I encounter a popup in Chrome that says:
"Change your password. The password you just used was exposed in a data breach. Change it now in Google Password Manager."
I tried to disable this popup by passing the following arguments when launching the browser:
Args = new[]
{
    "--disable-features=PasswordLeakDetection", // Disables password leak detection
    "--no-sandbox",                             // For easier execution in Docker
    "--disable-save-password-bubble"            // Disables save password prompts
}

However, the popup still appears.
My Questions:
How can I completely disable this popup in Chrome using Puppeteer?
Is it possible to programmatically remove this popup using selectors or any other logic in Puppeteer?
Additional Info:
Puppeteer version: 20.0.5
Chrome version: 131.0.6778.86
Operating System: Windows
Thank you for your help!
using PuppeteerSharp;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var browserTasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int browserIndex = 1; browserIndex <= 3; browserIndex++)
        {
            int tabCount = 5;

            browserTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
                {
                    ExecutablePath = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
                    Headless = false,
                    Args = new[]
                    {
                        "--disable-features=PasswordLeakDetection", // Disables password leak detection
                        "--no-sandbox",                             // For easier execution in Docker
                        "--disable-save-password-bubble"            // Disables save password prompts
                    },
                    DefaultViewport = null
                });

                var tabTasks = new List<Task>();

                for (int tabIndex = 1; tabIndex <= tabCount; tabIndex++)
                {
                    int counterTab = tabIndex;

                    tabTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

                        await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);
                        page.Request += async (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            var headers = e.Request.Headers;
                            headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
                            headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
                            headers["Expires"] = "0";
                            await e.Request.ContinueAsync(new Payload { Headers = headers });
                        };

                        await page.GoToAsync("https://www.saucedemo.com");
                        await page.TypeAsync("#user-name", "standard_user");
                        await page.TypeAsync("#password", "secret_sauce");
                        await page.ClickAsync("[name='login-button']");

                        Console.WriteLine($"Browser {browserIndex}, Tab {counterTab}: Login executed.");

                        //await page.CloseAsync();
                    }));
                }

                await Task.WhenAll(tabTasks);
                //await browser.CloseAsync();
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(browserTasks);

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"All tasks completed in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


You should add a minimal reproducable code, I just tested a script with a demo url, and it totally worked, no password leak message, nothing. http://demo.wpjobboard.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpjb-job

I was getting this error on saucedemo.com, the site is specifically made just for automated testing.
And getting that prompt from chrome is not constant.
My code works in multithreading, maybe that's the problem.

I was able to reproduce this issue. Let me see.

For me this did not happen with the original puppeteer written in JS. However I could see this became an issue on the puppeteer-sharp version even though it set the flags correctly.
For now, The solution seem to be disabling the message center popups altogether, which can be done with suppress-message-center-popups chrome flag.
Here is how I used this in the code,
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
  Headless = false,
  Args = ["--suppress-message-center-popups"]
});

Result,


I got the same results using this part of the code:
Args = [‘--suppress-message-center-popups’]
all the same chrome warns me to change my password.
